# SSRS 2016 - Date Range Filter for "This Week"

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and Report Builder. I run SSRS 2016.

I have a report that is looking at a SharePoint list, the report pulls in the data fine but I need to filter a date field to only show dates from "this week" - as in:

I have a column called "Created Date" and I run the report at 5 pm on the last day of the week (Friday) - The report should only produce all of the items created within the last 5 days (Monday to Friday (including Today, Friday)

I know how to filter on items created today using the =Today() expression, but I have not been able to get anything to work for items created within the last working week.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use 2 Parameters, say `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo`. Then you can filter your data to only include data where the Created Date is between `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo`.

If the report will always be run on a Friday, and you want Monday to Friday's data, then the expressions for your parameters would respectively be: `=DateAdd("d", -5, Today()` and `=Today()`.

Comment: Thank you for that! - You will have to hand-hold me though, I am completely new to this, sorry. What I was using was the "Tablix Properties" Filter (right-clicking on the table and selection Tablix properties --> Filters), selecting Add --> **Expression** = Created Date (from the SharePoint List) --> **Operator** is <= and **value** is where I was attempting to add: `=DateAdd("d", -5, Today()`

Comment: You can do it there as well. I prefer to use parameters, but kif you want to directly put the filter in the tablix that's fine.

Comment: I would also suggest do the filtering on the dataset instead of the tablix for performance, unless the is a very good reason not to

Comment: The idea is that if you have six years of data, your query will pull all six years across the wire from your database, and then your tablix will filter out just the week you're interested in. Much better to only pull the data you want in the first place.